# Discounts in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, discount

I have a multi-seller marketplace built on magento. I need to offer discounts on the site such that:

1. Only registered users can avail the discount
2. Discount amount has an upper limit (e.g. 10% off cart value but a max discount of $100 only) that I can define

Do you think there is a plugin that addresses these requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promotions - > Shopping Cart Price Rules

**1st Rule for 10% Discount**

```
Condition -   if subtotal equals or less than 1000 ( for thousand 10% discount is 100 ).
```

Percent of product price discount
Discount amount = 10

**2nd Rule for 100 Discount**

```
Condition -  if subtotal is greater than 1000
```

Fixed amount discount for whole cart
Discount amount = 100

**To enable for only logged in Users**

In Rule information -> Customer Groups
Select the customer groups except NOT LOGGED IN

Answer (score 0):

You can configure such things in  magento admin panel. 
Goto

**Promotions ->Catalog Price rules.**

there you can write rules as per your wish

Comment: I can find all the rules but how to address this one - max discount of $100 on a coupon of 10% off cart value

Comment: let me check and edit.